# Getting values from list (right side of colon)

Tags: r

I'm new to R so I'm sure this is simple but I can't figure it out. You can see the structure of my object n below. I want to loop through n and take each non-null value from the right side of the colon (e.g. "57454470") and apply a function to it.

```
> str(n)
List of 1
 $ :List of 10
  ..$ 15793766: NULL
  ..$ 15793767: chr "57454470"
  ..$ 15793769: chr "123652395"
  ..$ 15793770: chr "38098549"
  ..$ 15793771: chr "56864789"
  ..$ 15793776: chr "38722835"
  ..$ 15793779: chr "37962343"
  ..$ 15793784: chr "2100162920"
  ..$ 15793787: chr "2099439832"
  ..$ 15793791: chr "37992986"
  ..- attr(*, "dim")= int 10
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ rmaddrs$ReportID: chr [1:10] "15793766" "15793767" "15793769" "15793770" ...
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language by.data.frame(data = rmaddrs, INDICES = rmaddrs$ReportID, FUN = getValueFromXML)
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "by"
```

Here is the result of dput:

```
  dput(n[1])
    list(structure(list(`15793766` = NULL, `15793767` = "57454470", 
        `15793769` = "123652395", `15793770` = "38098549", `15793771` = "56864789", 
        `15793776` = "38722835", `15793779` = "37962343", `15793784` = "2100162920", 
        `15793787` = "2099439832", `15793791` = "37992986"), .Dim = 10L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        `rmaddrs$ReportID` = c("15793766", "15793767", "15793769", 
        "15793770", "15793771", "15793776", "15793779", "15793784", 
        "15793787", "15793791")), .Names = "rmaddrs$ReportID"), call = by.data.frame(data = rmaddrs, 
        INDICES = rmaddrs$ReportID, FUN = getValueFromXML), class = "by"))
```

UPDATE: I removed the "print" testing and I'm trying to use mean() for a better test.

```
sapply(n[1], function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Then I had to use unlist and as.numeric and now I think I have what I need to use my custom function.

Comment: Surely your function is not print.

Comment: No. I said "as a test."  Surely you can be more helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, but print is not a good test function since it prints as a side effect. It's not obvious from the question if that is confusing you.

Comment: It was, thanks. Gregor helped with his answer and comments below. I will update my question since I still can't get sapply to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using `sapply` it prints everything, but then it also returns  the object which (since it isn't assigned) is also printed. To avoid the printing of the returned object, you can wrap in `invisible()` or assign it

```
invisible(sapply(n[1], print))
xx = sapply(n[1], print)
```

(Note: this printing is just like if you enter `1 + 1` in the console, the resulting `2` will print. But if you enter `x = 1 + 1` nothing prints. I also simplified your `sapply` by omitting the anonymous function, but that isn't related to your issue.)

Comment: That helps but doesn't get to the core of my question, which is how to extract the values on the right side of the colon only (i.e. n[[1]], for example).

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean, but your use of `n[[1]]` is confusing since `n[[1]]` is a list of 10... maybe you mean you want `n[[1]][[1]]`, `n[[1]][[2]]`, etc? And all of those individual elements have names and values, by "*the right side of the colon*" you mean the you want the values to be printed without names? I.e, `print(unname(n[[1]][[1]]))`, `print(unname(n[[1]][[2]])`? So maybe you want `function(x) print(unname(x))`? Before I do any more work, could you please (1) reproducibly share a sample of your data with `dput()` and (2) for that sample explicitly show your desired output?

Comment: You're right, thanks! I added the results of dput(n[1]) to my question. I do want n[[1]][1] apparently, I thought I had tested that. I'll see if that allows me to use my custom function.

Comment: do you want to put your comment into your answer so people understand that print was only half my problem and I can mark your answer as accepted?